# Nonsense formatting of asm snippet

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

In an [answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69685404) I have a code block containing asm code, starting with `~~~nasm` (I also tried just `~~~`), and it produces nonsense formatting of the assembly:

[image]

I have no clue what's going on, the highlighted elements seem more or less random (e.g,. on one line the `0` in `r10` is highlighted, while on the next like all of `r10` is highlighted, and random words like `no` in the comments are highlighted).

How can I fix this to get proper nasm/asm highlighting?

Comment: Apparently, from inspecting the source code, Highlight.js is interpreting your code as Perl.

Comment: It looks like there's no highlight grammar installed for assembly, based on https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js (search for `grmr_bash` to find the list).

Comment: If Assembly syntax highlighting isn't supported, you can remove the syntax highlighting by using `~~~none`.

Comment: @NatRiddle - lol, just my luck that it chooses perl of course. I guess perl and asm are similarly inscruitable at times.

Comment: I just tried to swipe on the right on your screenshot... :)

Answer (score 8):

The Highlight.js engine that SO uses now simply doesn't support syntax-highlighting for assembly language.

Mind you, neither did the old Google Prettify that used to be used here on Stack Overflow prior to [the switchover to highlight.js at the end of September 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter). I had submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify/pull/486) many years ago, back in 2017, to Google Prettify that added support for x86 assembly code, but it never got merged. This lack of maintenance on Prettify was a big reason why Stack Exchange felt compelled to switch to highlight.js.

Anyway, since highlight.js doesn't support it, it doesn't matter what "hint" string you put after the code fence. As has been mentioned in the comments by Nat Riddle, apparently highlight.js's "automatic" detection is interpreting it as Perl code. In my experience, highlight.js's "automatic" detection is hilariously wrong and should generally just be *suppressed*:

````
```none
````

should do the trick. Better than wrong highlighting, at least.

###### See also: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109)

Comment: Thanks Cody. Turns out `x86asm` is supported by highlight.js (using that hint, which is different than some other highlighters), but it's not the in the handful of languages SO supports out of the many supported by highlight.js. I guess the reluctance to add more is to avoid bloating the javascript, but it seems like there are technical solutions to this problem (e.g., loading per-language javascript dynamically, at least for the more obscure langs).

Comment: I added a feature-request to see if we can make x86 asm a supported language: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412543/support-x86asm-as-a-highlighted-language