# Support x86asm as a highlighted language

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I would like to see x86 asm (Intel syntax) supported as a highlighted language.

It is already supported by highlight.js as `x86asm`, and there are more than 15,000 questions in the [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) tag alone and thousands more in variants such as [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-64). The tag is active with a rich variety of beginner and advanced questions and the tag wiki is a work of art curated by SO titan Peter Cordes among others.

That's more questions than some languages which are already supported, e.g., [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) with ~7,000 questions.

Finally, x86asm has a very simple syntax, so if the highlight.js implementation is good it should be a fairly lightweight thing to include.

Comment: [It's an old problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401387/6865932), I'll always contribute to the cause whenever I can.

Comment: @anastaciu - yes, but there's hope now after the switch to highlight.js since it supports x86asm out of the box, so it's just a matter of SO "flipping the flag" (so to speak).

Comment: I fully support this, many times I have looked for ASM-related questions and solutions to problems regarding LLVM, Specific CPU instructions, and registers. Syntax highlighting would be a very welcome addition.

Comment: I like the idea, but would this apply to only Intel format assembly, or to AT&T format assembly? There are many questions with AT&T formatted assembly that lack the `att` tag. Would this create a demand for syntax highlighting the assembly languages of other CPUs?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - highlight.js only supports Intel syntax, which is the default choice in any case among people who frequent the x86 tag.

Comment: From a comment to the question that @anastaciu linked, [Peter Cordes has posted an answer arguing precisely the same thing on the MSE announcement of the switch to highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter/354368#354368). So, if you're upvoting this, you should probably be upvoting that, too.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree - this would be a fantastic addition.